# Why does height 100% work on absolutely positioned element?

Tags: html, css, css-position

As far as I know for the height to work as percentage the container element must have a specific height mentioned. But this doesn't hold true for absolutely positioned element with the ancestor being relatively positioned. Here is a working example of what I meant:

```css
.container {
  width: 400px;
  background: cyan;
  text-align: right;
  position: relative;
  color: white;
}

.child {
  width: 90%;
  height: 100%;
  background: blue;
}

.absolute {
  position: absolute;
}

.second {
  margin-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child absolute">Absolute</div>
  one <br> two <br> three <br> one <br> two <br> three <br>
</div>
<div class="container second">
  <div class="child">Static</div>
  one <br> two <br> three <br> one <br> two <br> three <br>
</div>
```

As you can see the absolutely placed div applied 100% height onto it but not the statically positioned div. Why?

Comment: Your `child` element, as you're not describing a `position`, it's by default `position: static;`. To calculate your `height: 100%;`, the parent element should have a `height` defined, but it doesn't. In this case, the browser won't modify/calculate the heights of its children if they're not absolutely positioned (so they will appear matching the size of their contents). The `position: absolute;` case is different, as it's calculated after the parent element has been rendered.

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visudet.html#the-height-property

Answer (score 0):

From MDN

> relative
>       This keyword lays out all elements as though the element were not positioned, and then adjusts the element's position, without changing layout (and thus leaving a gap for the element where it would have been had it not been positioned). The effect of position:relative on table-*-group, table-row, table-column, table-cell, and table-caption elements is undefined.

[Read more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position). Is very nicely described.

Comment: How does this imply that absolutely positioned element will apply height percentage correctly?

Comment: Yes, but always remember - absolute positioning refers to his parent element. From MDN: _"Do not leave space for the item. Instead, position it at a Specified position relative to its closest positioned ancestor if any, or otherwise relative to the initial containing block."_

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/) is a great read about the different position types:

**Absolute** is relative to the parent element and is not affected by other elements and are removed from the flow of the page i.e. you can see the list with one, two, three unaffected.

It's height is 100% as .child specifies.

Comment: I read the csstricks article. It only explains about css positioning but doesn't tell why absolute positioned element respects height in percentages while statically positioned elements not.

Comment: Does the 'Definition of containing block' section of [this](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#containing-block-details) article help?

Comment: Somewhat. This portion seem to imply the observable effect: _If the height of the containing block is not specified explicitly (i.e., it depends on content height), and this element is not **absolutely positioned**, the value computes to 'auto'._